# save output of porter stemming algorithm to text file

Tags: c#, algorithm, stemming, porter-stemmer

i have this porter algorithm code in c#,can someone tell me how to save the output of this code to txt file? also do i input name of a file or its contents?

using System;
using System.IO;

namespace porter {
    /*

```
   Porter stemmer in CSharp, based on the Java port. The original paper is in

       Porter, 1980, An algorithm for suffix stripping, Program, Vol. 14,
       no. 3, pp 130-137,

   See also http://www.tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer

   History:

   Release 1

   Bug 1 (reported by Gonzalo Parra 16/10/99) fixed as marked below.
   The words 'aed', 'eed', 'oed' leave k at 'a' for step 3, and b[k-1]
   is then out outside the bounds of b.

   Release 2

   Similarly,

   Bug 2 (reported by Steve Dyrdahl 22/2/00) fixed as marked below.
   'ion' by itself leaves j = -1 in the test for 'ion' in step 5, and
   b[j] is then outside the bounds of b.

   Release 3

   Considerably revised 4/9/00 in the light of many helpful suggestions
   from Brian Goetz of Quiotix Corporation (brian@quiotix.com).

   Release 4

*/

/**
  * Stemmer, implementing the Porter Stemming Algorithm
  *
  * The Stemmer class transforms a word into its root form.  The input
  * word can be provided a character at time (by calling add()), or at once
  * by calling one of the various stem(something) methods.
  */

class Stemmer {
    private char[] b;
    private int i,     /* offset into b */
        i_end, /* offset to end of stemmed word */
        j, k;
    private static int INC = 50;
    /* unit of size whereby b is increased */

    public Stemmer() {
        b = new char[INC];
        i = 0;
        i_end = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Add a character to the word being stemmed.  When you are finished
     * adding characters, you can call stem(void) to stem the word.
     */

    public void add(char ch) {
        if (i == b.Length) {
            char[] new_b = new char[i+INC];
            for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
                new_b[c] = b[c];
            b = new_b;
        }
        b[i++] = ch;
    }


    /** Adds wLen characters to the word being stemmed contained in a portion
     * of a char[] array. This is like repeated calls of add(char ch), but
     * faster.
     */

    public void add(char[] w, int wLen) {
        if (i+wLen >= b.Length) {
            char[] new_b = new char[i+wLen+INC];
            for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
                new_b[c] = b[c];
            b = new_b;
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < wLen; c++)
            b[i++] = w[c];
    }

    /**
     * After a word has been stemmed, it can be retrieved by toString(),
     * or a reference to the internal buffer can be retrieved by getResultBuffer
     * and getResultLength (which is generally more efficient.)
     */
    public override string ToString() {
        return new String(b,0,i_end);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the length of the word resulting from the stemming process.
     */
    public int getResultLength() {
        return i_end;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a reference to a character buffer containing the results of
     * the stemming process.  You also need to consult getResultLength()
     * to determine the length of the result.
     */
    public char[] getResultBuffer() {
        return b;
    }

    /* cons(i) is true <=> b[i] is a consonant. */
    private bool cons(int i) {
        switch (b[i]) {
            case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': return false;
            case 'y': return (i==0) ? true : !cons(i-1);
            default: return true;
        }
    }

    /* m() measures the number of consonant sequences between 0 and j. if c is
       a consonant sequence and v a vowel sequence, and <..> indicates arbitrary
       presence,

          <c><v>       gives 0
          <c>vc<v>     gives 1
          <c>vcvc<v>   gives 2
          <c>vcvcvc<v> gives 3
          ....
    */
    private int m() {
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            if (i > j) return n;
            if (! cons(i)) break; i++;
        }
        i++;
        while(true) {
            while(true) {
                if (i > j) return n;
                if (cons(i)) break;
                i++;
            }
            i++;
            n++;
            while(true) {
                if (i > j) return n;
                if (! cons(i)) break;
                i++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    /* vowelinstem() is true <=> 0,...j contains a vowel */
    private bool vowelinstem() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= j; i++)
            if (! cons(i))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    /* doublec(j) is true <=> j,(j-1) contain a double consonant. */
    private bool doublec(int j) {
        if (j < 1)
            return false;
        if (b[j] != b[j-1])
            return false;
        return cons(j);
    }

    /* cvc(i) is true <=> i-2,i-1,i has the form consonant - vowel - consonant
       and also if the second c is not w,x or y. this is used when trying to
       restore an e at the end of a short word. e.g.

          cav(e), lov(e), hop(e), crim(e), but
          snow, box, tray.

    */
    private bool cvc(int i) {
        if (i < 2 || !cons(i) || cons(i-1) || !cons(i-2))
            return false;
        int ch = b[i];
        if (ch == 'w' || ch == 'x' || ch == 'y')
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private bool ends(String s) {
        int l = s.Length;
        int o = k-l+1;
        if (o < 0)
            return false;
        char[] sc = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            if (b[o+i] != sc[i])
                return false;
        j = k-l;
        return true;
    }

    /* setto(s) sets (j+1),...k to the characters in the string s, readjusting
       k. */
    private void setto(String s) {
        int l = s.Length;
        int o = j+1;
        char[] sc = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            b[o+i] = sc[i];
        k = j+l;
    }

    /* r(s) is used further down. */
    private void r(String s) {
        if (m() > 0)
            setto(s);
    }

    /* step1() gets rid of plurals and -ed or -ing. e.g.
           caresses  ->  caress
           ponies    ->  poni
           ties      ->  ti
           caress    ->  caress
           cats      ->  cat

           feed      ->  feed
           agreed    ->  agree
           disabled  ->  disable

           matting   ->  mat
           mating    ->  mate
           meeting   ->  meet
           milling   ->  mill
           messing   ->  mess

           meetings  ->  meet

    */

    private void step1() {
        if (b[k] == 's') {
            if (ends("sses"))
                k -= 2;
            else if (ends("ies"))
                setto("i");
            else if (b[k-1] != 's')
                k--;
        }
        if (ends("eed")) {
            if (m() > 0)
                k--;
        } else if ((ends("ed") || ends("ing")) && vowelinstem()) {
            k = j;
            if (ends("at"))
                setto("ate");
            else if (ends("bl"))
                setto("ble");
            else if (ends("iz"))
                setto("ize");
            else if (doublec(k)) {
                k--;
                int ch = b[k];
                if (ch == 'l' || ch == 's' || ch == 'z')
                    k++;
            }
            else if (m() == 1 && cvc(k)) setto("e");
        }
    }

    /* step2() turns terminal y to i when there is another vowel in the stem. */
    private void step2() {
        if (ends("y") && vowelinstem())
            b[k] = 'i';
    }

    /* step3() maps double suffices to single ones. so -ization ( = -ize plus
       -ation) maps to -ize etc. note that the string before the suffix must give
       m() > 0. */
    private void step3() {
        if (k == 0)
            return;

        /* For Bug 1 */
        switch (b[k-1]) {
            case 'a':
                if (ends("ational")) { r("ate"); break; }
                if (ends("tional")) { r("tion"); break; }
                break;
            case 'c':
                if (ends("enci")) { r("ence"); break; }
                if (ends("anci")) { r("ance"); break; }
                break;
            case 'e':
                if (ends("izer")) { r("ize"); break; }
                break;
            case 'l':
                if (ends("bli")) { r("ble"); break; }
                if (ends("alli")) { r("al"); break; }
                if (ends("entli")) { r("ent"); break; }
                if (ends("eli")) { r("e"); break; }
                if (ends("ousli")) { r("ous"); break; }
                break;
            case 'o':
                if (ends("ization")) { r("ize"); break; }
                if (ends("ation")) { r("ate"); break; }
                if (ends("ator")) { r("ate"); break; }
                break;
            case 's':
                if (ends("alism")) { r("al"); break; }
                if (ends("iveness")) { r("ive"); break; }
                if (ends("fulness")) { r("ful"); break; }
                if (ends("ousness")) { r("ous"); break; }
                break;
            case 't':
                if (ends("aliti")) { r("al"); break; }
                if (ends("iviti")) { r("ive"); break; }
                if (ends("biliti")) { r("ble"); break; }
                break;
            case 'g':
                if (ends("logi")) { r("log"); break; }
                break;
            default :
                break;
        }
    }

    /* step4() deals with -ic-, -full, -ness etc. similar strategy to step3. */
    private void step4() {
        switch (b[k]) {
            case 'e':
                if (ends("icate")) { r("ic"); break; }
                if (ends("ative")) { r(""); break; }
                if (ends("alize")) { r("al"); break; }
                break;
            case 'i':
                if (ends("iciti")) { r("ic"); break; }
                break;
            case 'l':
                if (ends("ical")) { r("ic"); break; }
                if (ends("ful")) { r(""); break; }
                break;
            case 's':
                if (ends("ness")) { r(""); break; }
                break;
        }
    }

    /* step5() takes off -ant, -ence etc., in context <c>vcvc<v>. */
    private void step5() {
        if (k == 0)
            return;

        /* for Bug 1 */
        switch ( b[k-1] ) {
            case 'a':
                if (ends("al")) break; return;
            case 'c':
                if (ends("ance")) break;
                if (ends("ence")) break; return;
            case 'e':
                if (ends("er")) break; return;
            case 'i':
                if (ends("ic")) break; return;
            case 'l':
                if (ends("able")) break;
                if (ends("ible")) break; return;
            case 'n':
                if (ends("ant")) break;
                if (ends("ement")) break;
                if (ends("ment")) break;
                /* element etc. not stripped before the m */
                if (ends("ent")) break; return;
            case 'o':
                if (ends("ion") && j >= 0 && (b[j] == 's' || b[j] == 't')) break;
                /* j >= 0 fixes Bug 2 */
                if (ends("ou")) break; return;
                /* takes care of -ous */
            case 's':
                if (ends("ism")) break; return;
            case 't':
                if (ends("ate")) break;
                if (ends("iti")) break; return;
            case 'u':
                if (ends("ous")) break; return;
            case 'v':
                if (ends("ive")) break; return;
            case 'z':
                if (ends("ize")) break; return;
            default:
                return;
        }
        if (m() > 1)
            k = j;
    }

    /* step6() removes a final -e if m() > 1. */
    private void step6() {
        j = k;

        if (b[k] == 'e') {
            int a = m();
            if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(k-1))
                k--;
        }
        if (b[k] == 'l' && doublec(k) && m() > 1)
            k--;
    }

    /** Stem the word placed into the Stemmer buffer through calls to add().
     * Returns true if the stemming process resulted in a word different
     * from the input.  You can retrieve the result with
     * getResultLength()/getResultBuffer() or toString().
     */
    public void stem() {
        k = i - 1;
        if (k > 1) {
            step1();
            step2();
            step3();
            step4();
            step5();
            step6();
        }
        i_end = k+1;
        i = 0;
    }

    /** Test program for demonstrating the Stemmer.  It reads text from a
     * a list of files, stems each word, and writes the result to standard
     * output. Note that the word stemmed is expected to be in lower case:
     * forcing lower case must be done outside the Stemmer class.
     * Usage: Stemmer file-name file-name ...
     */
    public static void Main( String[] args ) {
        if ( args.Length == 0 ) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Usage:  Stemmer <input file>" );
            return;
        }
        char[] w = new char[501];
        Stemmer s = new Stemmer();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            try {
                FileStream _in = new FileStream( args[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        int ch = _in.ReadByte();
                        if ( Char.IsLetter((char) ch)) {
                            int j = 0;
                            while(true) {
                                ch = Char.ToLower((char) ch);
                                w[j] = (char) ch;
                                if (j < 500)
                                    j++;
                                ch = _in.ReadByte();
                                if (!Char.IsLetter((char) ch)) {
                                    /* to test add(char ch) */
                                    for (int c = 0; c < j; c++)
                                        s.add(w[c]);
                                    /* or, to test add(char[] w, int j) */
                                    /* s.add(w, j); */
                                    s.stem();

                                    String u;

                                    /* and now, to test toString() : */
                                    u = s.ToString();

                                    /* to test getResultBuffer(), getResultLength() : */
                                    /* u = new String(s.getResultBuffer(), 0, s.getResultLength()); */

                                    Console.Write(u);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (ch < 0)
                            break;
                        Console.Write((char)ch);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ) {
                    Console.WriteLine("error reading " + args[i]);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ) {
                Console.WriteLine("file " + args[i] + " not found");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Start it in the console and put "> log.txt" behind the command. For java it would look like:

> java -ea -jar target/assembly/test.jar > log.txt

Comment: i was looking for a c# implementation

Answer (score 0):

Jalil Bayat student at university of Kurdistan Iran

You can try this code

```
 public static void  DoStemmer(String[] args)
        {
            String[] Final = new string[args.Length];
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                return ;
            }
            char[] w = new char[501];
            Stemmer s = new Stemmer();

            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                //try
                //{

                byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[i]);
               //using (FileStream _in = new FileStream(args[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                //try
                //{
                //Boolean Flag = false;
                int Size=array.Length;
                int Count = 0;
                int j = 0;
                Array.Clear(w, 0, w.Length);

                foreach (byte element in array)
                {
                    Count++;
                    int ch = element;
                    if (Char.IsLetter((char)ch))
                    {

                        //while (true)
                        //{
                            ch = Char.ToLower((char)ch);
                            w[j] = (char)ch;
                            if (j < 500)
                                j++;
                          //  ch = _in.ReadByte();
                            if (Count==Size)
                            {
                                /* to test add(char ch) */
                                for (int c = 0; c < j; c++)
                                    s.add(w[c]);
                                /* or, to test add(char[] w, int j) */
                                /* s.add(w, j); */
                                s.stem();

                                String u;

                                /* and now, to test toString() : */
                                u = s.ToString();

                                /* to test getResultBuffer(), getResultLength() : */
                                /* u = new String(s.getResultBuffer(), 0, s.getResultLength()); */

                                Final[i] = u;
                                break;
                            }
                        //}
                    }
                    if (ch < 0)
                        break;
                    Final[i] = ch.ToString();
                }
                //    }
                //    catch (IOException)
                //    {
                //        MessageBox.Show("o");
                //        break;  

                //    }
                //}
                //catch (FileNotFoundException)
                //{
                //    break;
                //    MessageBox.Show("no");

                //}

            }

            FileStream sw = new FileStream(@"D:\patttt.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(sw);

            for (int jj = 0; jj < Final.Length; jj++)
                fs.WriteLine(Final[jj]);
        }
```